# How to rotate + flip element with CSS

Tags: css, css-transforms

The transform property lets you rotate or flip, but how can you do both at the same time?  Say I want to rotate an element 90 degrees and flip it horizontally?  Both are done with the same property, so the latter overwrites the former.  Here's an example fiddle for convenience:

http://jsfiddle.net/DtNh6/

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: scaleX(-1);
```

Comment: https://dev.danlobo.co.uk/pure-css-coverflow-slider/index.html uses input:checked~ selector with both radio buttons and checkboxes

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I fiddled with jsfiddle, and this worked:

```
$('#photo').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1)');
```

To relate it to your question, the resulting CSS looks like

```
transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
```

Comment: Any idea if that's supported across browsers as well?  Thanks!

Comment: The space separated properties bit is in the spec -- how well "in the spec" maps to "supported by browsers" is anybody's guess, but I'd be confident using it I think (in so far as I'd rely on browsers implementing transforms at all)

Comment: I like how I answered the exact same thing before him and you marked his as the answer.

Answer (score 21):

The properties can be delimited by spaces, like so.

```
transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
```

Answer (score 10):

For future generations, a more complete answer:

```
.rotate2{ /*leaning left <- */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(270deg);
    transform:rotate(270deg);
}
.rotate4{ /*upside down*/
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.rotate6{ /*leaning right -> */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.rotate8{ /*vertical flip*/ /*upside-down mirror*/
    -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
    transform: scale(1, -1);
}
.rotate10{ /*vertical flip*/ /*upside-down*/
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1, -1);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1, -1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1, -1);
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1, -1);
}
.rotate12{ /*horizontal flip*/ /*left-right mirror*/
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
.rotate14{ /*horizontal flip*/ /*left-right mirror*/
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(-1, 1);
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(-1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
element {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

for more info here is the link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/flip-an-image/